# Wordpress ignoring sub-directory, hit or miss

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site running on WordPress. I am testing out a new site on our server under a subdirectory (`sandbox/`). For the new site I'm using an .htaccess rewrite rule similar to WP that rewrites to clean urls. I'm finding that pages that have an equivalent path in WP redirect to the WP page.

For instance, I have one page that has an url of `/sandbox/supplies/information` which redirects correctly to the new site. However, I have another page that is at `/sandbox/events/` that will redirect to the base director at `/events/`.

After looking around at people's similar problems, I've tried using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sandbox/ [NC]` and other variants (`!^sandbox/.$` and the like), but it doesn't seem to have any effect whatsoever. I've copied the two .htaccess files below.

Thanks in advance for your time. I hope I explained the situation well enough.

*Base .htaccess*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !sandbox/ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

*Sub-directory (sandbox/) .htaccess*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /sandbox/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well .. I have only used this line in main .htaccess file, and it all worked fine on my simulated setup:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sandbox/ [NC]
```

May I suggest changing `Options +FollowSymLinks` to `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` (or maybe you have tried that already)?

If URL has `/sandbox/` part and your `/sandbox/.htaccess` does not have `RewriteOption inherit` line, then rules from parent .htaccess are NOT getting used at all.

---

How much control do you have over Apache? Can you edit config files (httpd.conf or httpd-vhost.conf)? If you can -- enable rewrite debugging (`RewriteLogLevel 9`) and try that problematic URL -- you should see exactly what is going on (maybe it getting redirected from within php application?). Other than that your rules are absolutely fine for me.

---

Don't know if this is good idea or not .. but in case you will be unable to figure out the reason for such behaviour, consider joining these 2 .htaccess files into 1 (changes are minimal).

Comment: -MultiViews fixed it. Thanks so much! I am just getting my feet wet with .htaccess and had not heard of this option before. Because I like to understand why something works, let me see if I'm getting this right:

MultiViews causes the server to search for a substitute index file if one is not specified in the user's url (in this case, something like www.domain.com/sandbox/folder/). In my case, I'm guessing it searched first in the base folder, found the index.php file there and served that? Thus it never came to use the index.php file in the /sandbox folder?

Comment: TBH, I'm not 100% sure myself how exactly it does work in some situations -- sometimes I see it uses .htaccess file that is _outside_ of website root (1 folder up). In such cases I just need to adjust to the current situation ... as a lot can depend on what modules are enabled and what options are set (how Apache is configured) -- something may work with no issues at all on my box but will not work on GoDaddy (for example). `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` is quite common recipe for shared hosting environment. On this particular case I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Well, it is shared hosting, so it certainly fits that bill. Again, thanks for your help. You saved me a ton of frustration!